# Entropy and resonance

Tags: entropy, resonance

I'm interested in determining whether the entropy of a vibrating string fixed at two ends can be expressed as a function of frequency. Particularly, the entropy at resonant frequencies. I'm not sure how to define the microstates of this system. I have had no luck finding information on this approach and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: For a pure mechanical system like that, thermodynamical concepts as entropy are not well suited. There is a good discussion in https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Thermodynamics_and_Chemical_Equilibrium_(Ellgen)/12%3A_Applications_of_the_Thermodynamic_Criteria_for_Change/12.01%3A_Mechanical_Processes

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was curious about resonating bonds and whether resonance is a high or low entropy condition. I thought a vibrating string would be a simple start.